Looking for a shim or fallback for CSS @property for older Safari browsers
I'm looking for a fallback or shim for CSS @property.
This works in Chrome, and Safari 17, but not in earlier versions of Safari. I'm hoping to at least support Safari 15 and higher.
@property --someVar {
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
}

I have tried to simply declare the variable like this:
html { 
    --someVar: 0;
}

But that does not appear to work.

What are you doing with this property? I guess it's some animation. That's what you'd create a shim for. The Web Animation API might help in this case.
